# Can custom scripts be added into the Meebo toolbar?

Tags: meebo

Does the Meebo toolbar enable the adding of a custom script that will allow us to insert our own Javascript script -- or something equivalent (e.g. something equivalent to the [wibiya item](http://www.wibiya.com/web_application))?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is now possible.

Question:

> 1. Does the Meebo toolbar enable the adding of a custom script that will allow us to insert our own Javascript script — or something equivalent (e.g. something equivalent to the wibiya item: http://www.wibiya.com/web_application… )

Answer:

> Yes, you can do this either via the custom button interface on the dashboard or via the bar button API directly on the page.

The question was answered by an admin on the [Meebo forums](http://forum.meebo.com/forums/36028-meebo-bar-for-publishers/suggestions/1766757-some-questions-about-the-meebo-bar).

Comment: And it seems you were the one that asked it there as well.

Answer (score 0):

Reply from Meebo:

> We are literally days away from having this available via the
>   dashboard. Until then, you can add custom buttons that do this using
>   our API. This API documentation is available from the Docs section of
>   the dashboard (you will get a dashboard when you create a Meebo bar
>   via meebo.com/websites). Using this API (and in a few days your
>   dashboard) you can create buttons that display link menus, execute
>   javascript, or show an iFramed website or chunk of HTML/JavaScript.